# How to call facebook's executeAndWait() in AsyncTask task

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-asynctask, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to improve my design and put things in their proper place. So I want to move away from putting my logic inside my activity and all. To do so, I created the following classes:

```
public class FacebookLoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebook_login_activity);

         new FacebookName().execute(this);
    }

    private class FacebookName extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Activity... params) {

            CustomStatusCallback customStatusCallback = new CustomStatusCallback() {

                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                        CustomGraphUserCallback customerGraphUserCallback = new CustomGraphUserCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    setResult(user.getName());
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        Request.newMeRequest(session, customerGraphUserCallback).executeAndWait();
                    }
                }
            };

            Session.openActiveSession(params[0], true, customStatusCallback);
            return customStatusCallback.getResult();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView facebookName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.facebookName);
            facebookName.setText("Hi " + result);
        }

    };

}
```

Here are the other custom classes I created in order to hold the value and pass it up back to `protected void onPostExecute(String result)` :

```
public abstract class CustomGraphUserCallback implements Request.GraphUserCallback {

    private String result;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    protected void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

Here is my CustomStatusCallback:

```
public abstract class CustomStatusCallback implements StatusCallback {

    private String result;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at com.facebook.Response.fromHttpConnection(Response.java:301)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at com.facebook.Request.executeConnectionAndWait(Request.java:1564)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1463)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1432)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1414)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at com.facebook.Request.executeAndWait(Request.java:1386)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at com.facebook.Request.executeAndWait(Request.java:1268)
02-28 21:32:08.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):    at com.blahblah.FacebookLoginActivity$FacebookName$1.call(FacebookLoginActivity.java:47)
```

Can you help me please? Again, I know how to make it work by using `executeAsync()` and put everything in the main action.

Thanks in advance guys and girls :)

Answer (score 0):

Here Is how you do that:

```
private class FBUserInfoTask extends AsyncTask<Session, Void, Map<String, Object>>
{
    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> doInBackground(Session[] session) // session state should be OPENED
    {
        Request request = new Request(session[0], "me"); //use any graph api here instead of "me" 
        Response response = request.executeAndWait();
        GraphObject obj = response.getGraphObject();
        Map<String, Object> map =  obj.asMap();
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Map<String, Object> result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.d("User Name:", (String) result.get("userId"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution won't work for me - it still throws same exception